# Is there a stand-alone version of the ux.stackexchange wireframe editor?

Tags: discussion, design

Just saw the wysiwyg wireframe editor in ux.stackexchange.com and I love it.  Just the right amount of simplicity & capability.

Does this exist as a stand-alone site?  I'd love to be able to create simple wireframes that I can revise later on without the typical we'll-give-it-to-you-for-free-this-month-and-change-the-rules-next-month rigmarole.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

It's [Balsamiq Mockups](http://balsamiq.com/products/mockups/).

You can see this in the *Help > About Balsamiq Mockups* menu.

[image: screenshot of about screen]

Comment: I love that you can [integrate Balsamiq right into google drive](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/balsamiq-mockups/pplbmgaodhjmbklkgkgmlghaekcfhhkk) for $5/mo.  Brilliant.

Answer (score 0):

Indeed. It is a tool you can buy a licence for, and run it locally on your own system using Adobe Air.